# windows 7 firewall blocks connection to named sql instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, firewall

I want to connect to a named instance of sql server wich runs on a cluster. When I disable the firewall on my windows 7 client machine, I can connect. However, when I activate the firewall, the named instance cannot be found. A named instance of a different server, not on a cluster, can be connected with the client firewall on.

How can I setup my client firewall so I can connect to the named instance that runs on a cluster with my firewall enabled?

Note: What I can do is to disable firewall, connect to the named instance and re-enable the firewall again. After that the connection to the named instance works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based on you having Windows 2008 R2 on your SQL Server

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
- SQL Server Network Configuration
- Protocols for *named_instance*
- IP Addresses
- Delete 0 from TCP Dynamic Ports else it won't work (you might as well switch the firewall off) and put an unused port number in TCP Port, eg 7200
- Repeat the above line all down your list of IPs until you reach the bottom.
- Click OK

Add some rules:

Open firewall from Control Panel --> Advance Settings

Inbound rules --> New Rule

```
Name: Native SQL Server (TCP 1433)
Protocol: TCP
Port: 1433

Name: My Instance SQL Server (TCP 7200)
Protocol: TCP
Port: 7200

Name: SQL Server (UDP 1434)
Protocol: UDP
Port: 1434
```

REBOOT!!! (or restart the sql services)

Management Studio on your PC should now be able to access the new instance of the database on the server (assuming you don't have firewall restrictions on your own machine)

Comment: I've re-read your message again.  It should just be UDP 1434 that's causing the issue.  GL anyhow, just documenting what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open ports 445 and if you also need TCP/UDP connections to Sql Server - 1433, 1434

Comment: Tried that, opened up TCP 445, 1433 and 1434, opened up UDP 1433 and 1434. But no result.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.

I checked the Windows Firewall Log under %systemroot%\system32\logfiles\firewall\pfirewall.log and saw that UDP port 1434 was blocked:

```
2014-05-14 10:44:44 DROP UDP 12.121.12.121 13.131.131.131 1434 62370 168 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
```

To connect to a named instance that runs on a cluster you need to open the UDP port 1434 in your local windows firewall.

1. Open "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security". ("Run as administrator" could help)
2. Go To **"Inbound Rules"**.
3. On the actions menu on the right click "New Rule".
4. Select **"Custom"**, click next until you are on step "Protocol and Ports".
5. On "Protocol type" select "UDP".
6. On **"Remote port"** select "Specific ports" and write 1434.

   [image: Screenshot of step "Protocol and Ports"]
7. Click next until you reach step "Profile". I choose just "Domain" so that this rule only applies in the intranet of the company I worked for.
8. Click next and give it a meaningful name
9. Click finish and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Server uses Dynamic Ports, so it's not listening on 1433. If you don't want to change from using dynamic ports or you're running more than one SQL instance on the server, you can just let the sql server process listen on any port.

e.g. in Powershell

`New-NetFirewallRule -Name 'SQLServer' -DisplayName 'SQL Server' -Group "SQL Server" -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -Program "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<version#>.<instanceName>\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe"`